# psqlODBC won't load after installing MS SQL ODBC driver on RHEL 6

Tags: sql-server, linux, postgresql, isql

I had the PostgreSQL drivers working on my RHEL 6. But after I installed Microsoft® SQL Server® ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux I can no longer connect to PosgreSQL data sources. I can connect to SQL Server data sources fine.

When I had this same issue a week ago I uninstalled MS SQL Server ODBC driver from Linux and it fixed the issue. I removed MS SQL Server ODBC driver by executing the following commands:

```
rm /usr/bin/bcp
rm /usr/bin/sqlcmd
odbcinst -u -d -n "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
rm -r /opt/microsoft/sqlncli
```

I still had to copy the `psqlodbcw.so` file (MS drivers installation made them inaccessible despite their existence) from another Linux machine that had PostgreSQL drivers working.

Again, I needed to use MS SQL drivers and so installed again. With MS SQL drivers installed again - I again failed to connect to PostgreSQL drivers. Though, I did not uninstall MS SQL drivers and checked what was going on. This time around I found that the setup files had got deleted: `/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so`. However, replenishing the file did not fix the issue since I did not uninstall MS SQL as in the previous case.

I kept getting the following error message in spite of the file being present with `rwx` permisions:

```
[root@localhost lib64]# isql -v STUDENT dsname pwd12345
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
[root@localhost lib64]#
```

Here is a printout of the file permissions:

```
[root@localhost lib64]# ls -al p*.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     12 Dec  7 09:15 psqlodbc.so -> psqlodbcw.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 519496 Dec  7 09:35 psqlodbcw.so
```

and my `odbcinst.ini` file looks as follows:

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbc.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=4
```

I also referred to this link: http://mailman.unixodbc.org/pipermail/unixodbc-support/2010-September.txt

Output from running:

```
[root@localhost bin]# ldd /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff371ea000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f55f288f000)
    libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5 (0x00007f55f2667000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f55f2449000)
    libodbcinst.so.2 => not found
    libodbc.so.2 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f55f20b5000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f55f1e73000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f55f1b94000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f55f198f000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f55f1763000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f55f13c9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f55f11c4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f55f0fae000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f55f0d77000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f55f0b23000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d6f600000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f55f0918000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f55f0715000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f55f04fa000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f55f0298000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f55f0088000)
    libssl3.so => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so (0x00007f55efe4c000)
    libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007f55efc20000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f55ef8e3000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f55ef6bd000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007f55ef4b9000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007f55ef2b3000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f55ef076000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f55eee5c000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f55eec3c000)
```

I don't want to uninstall the MS SQL drivers from my Linux machine to get the PostgreSQL drivers to work. I want both drivers to work on Linux.

Craig Ringer suggested to run:

```
[root@localhost bin]# LD_DEBUG=libs isql -v STUDENT dsname pwd12345
     22029: find library=libodbc.so.1 [0]; searching
     22029:  search path=/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64/x86_64:/usr/lib64      (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libodbc.so.1
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libodbc.so.1
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/x86_64/libodbc.so.1
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1
     22029: 
     22029: find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
     22029:  search path=/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64      (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libdl.so.2
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libdl.so.2
     22029:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     22029:   trying file=/lib64/libdl.so.2
     22029: 
     22029: find library=libpthread.so.0 [0]; searching
     22029:  search path=/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64      (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libpthread.so.0
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
     22029:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     22029:   trying file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0
     22029: 
     22029: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
     22029:  search path=/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64      (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libc.so.6
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libc.so.6
     22029:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     22029:   trying file=/lib64/libc.so.6
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: prelink checking: ok
     22029: 
     22029: calling init: /lib64/libpthread.so.0
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling init: /lib64/libc.so.6
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling init: /lib64/libdl.so.2
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling init: /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: initialize program: isql
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: transferring control: isql
     22029: 
     22029: find library=libnss_files.so.2 [0]; searching
     22029:  search path=/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64      (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libnss_files.so.2
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libnss_files.so.2
     22029:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     22029:   trying file=/lib64/libnss_files.so.2
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling init: /lib64/libnss_files.so.2
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling init: /usr/lib64/gconv/UTF-16.so
     22029: 
     22029: find library=libssl.so.10 [0]; searching
     22029:  search path=/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64      (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libssl.so.10
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
     22029: 
     22029: find library=libpq.so.5 [0]; searching
     22029:  search path=/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64      (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libpq.so.5
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libpq.so.5
     22029: 
     22029: find library=libodbcinst.so.2 [0]; searching
     22029:  search path=/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64      (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libodbcinst.so.2
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2
     22029:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     22029:  search path=/lib64/tls/x86_64:/lib64/tls:/lib64/x86_64:/lib64:/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64        (system search path)
     22029:   trying file=/lib64/tls/x86_64/libodbcinst.so.2
     22029:   trying file=/lib64/tls/libodbcinst.so.2
     22029:   trying file=/lib64/x86_64/libodbcinst.so.2
     22029:   trying file=/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libodbcinst.so.2
     22029:   trying file=/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2
     22029: 
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
     22029: 
     22029: calling fini: isql [0]
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling fini: /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1 [0]
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling fini: /lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling fini: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0]
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling fini: /lib64/libnss_files.so.2 [0]
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling fini: /usr/lib64/gconv/UTF-16.so [0]
     22029: 
     22029: 
     22029: calling fini: /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     22029: 
[root@localhost bin]#
```

John Greene suggested:

```
[root@localhost bin]# ldd /usr/bin/isql 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff12cf9000)
    libodbc.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1 (0x0000003ef0800000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003d6fe00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003d70200000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d6fa00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d6f600000)
```

Comment: My guess is that the problem is not at the postgres side ( can you still connect? Try `telnet mydatabaseserve 5432`) If that fails: call Bill Gates.

Comment: Does the MS-SQL installer replace unixODBC with its own version? `md5sum` the binaries before and after. Does it mess with `/etc/ld.so.conf`? Did it change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? I'd say one way or another the MS SQL installer probably just clobbers your existing unixODBC install with no respect for packaging. You'll probably have to install it to a throwaway machine, collect up the files it produces, and make your own script to install it less intrusively.

Comment: You say "this time around"... so you've tried something multiple times. Please cover more detail. What exactly did you try each time? Please also add the output of `ldd /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so` and `LD_DEBUG=libs isql -v STUDENT dsname pwd12345` by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran: `rpm -q unixODBC` to check if unixODBC was still installed and unfortunately found out that it wasn't. The unixODBC drivers had somehow got uninstalled after installing SQL Server drivers without explicit intervention. I installed with `yum install unixODBC.x86_64`. And for the first time, I got both SQL Server drivers,PostgreSQL drivers and other drivers to connect to their respective data sources from the same machine (RHEL 6).

Answer (score 3):

Some really cool tricks to find out WHY it couldn't find the library file.

1. Where is your isql looking for the library?:
   `ldd <insert-path>/isql`
2. If there are no 'not found'... to be found, then try following the code to see where it did NOT open:
   `strace -f isql -v STUDENT dsname pwd12345`

   And look for the open failure (most commonly symbolic-link failures) like these:

   `open("/usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
3. Else, check the /etc/ld.so.conf or /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ for missing entries like

   `/usr/lib64`

---

I'd like to keep the following in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
`/usr/local/lib64`
`/usr/local/lib`
`/usr/lib64`
`/usr/lib`

If any changes were made to the /etc/ld.so.conf*, be sure to reload the library system cache (again):
 `ldconfig -v`

Comment: Rather than using `strace` to trace library loading, it's way nicer to use `LD_DEBUG=libs`. Try running `LD_DEBUG=help /bin/true` for help, and see `man ld.so`. For example `LD_DEBUG=libs psql -c 'SELECT 1;'`

Comment: Running `ldconfig -v` did not fix the issue. `strace` outputs too much info. I like LD_DEBUG.